# sklearn function transformer in pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, transformer-model

Writing my first pipeline for sk-learn I stumbled upon some issues when only a subset of columns is put into a pipeline:

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame({'classLabel':[0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0],
                   'categorical':[7,8,9,5,7,5,6,4],
                   'numeric1':[7,8,9,5,7,5,6,4],
                   'numeric2':[7,8,9,5,7,5,6,"N.A"]})
columnsNumber = ['numeric1']
XoneColumn = X[columnsNumber]
```

I use the `functionTransformer` like:

```
def extractSpecificColumn(X, columns):
    return X[columns]

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('features', FeatureUnion([
        ('continuous', Pipeline([
            ('numeric', FunctionTransformer(columnsNumber)),
            ('scale', StandardScaler())
        ]))
    ], n_jobs=1)),
    ('estimator', RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=50, criterion='entropy', n_jobs=-1))
])

cv.cross_val_score(pipeline, XoneColumn, y, cv=folds, scoring=kappaScore)
```

This results in: `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable` when the function transformer is enabled.

## edit:

If I instantiate a `ColumnExtractor` like below no error is returned. But isn't the `functionTransformer` meant just for simple cases like this one and should just work?

```
class ColumnExtractor(TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, columns):
        self.columns = columns

    def transform(self, X, *_):
        return X[self.columns]

    def fit(self, *_):
        return self
```

Comment: shouldn't `XoneColumn = X[columnsNumber]` be `XoneColumn = mydf[columnsNumber]`?

Comment: also looking at question 2 in your github the indices that are returned from `train_test_split` are the ordinal index values so I suggest using `.iloc` on the dfs `X_train = X.iloc[train_index]
    X_test = X.iloc[test_index]
    y_train = y.iloc[train_index]
    y_test = y.iloc[test_index]`

Comment: the sklearn code assumes everything is a np array, so you have a choice of either converting your pandas df to a np array using attribute `.values` or to use the `pandas` indexers such as `iloc`, `loc`, and `ix`

Comment: @EdChurn in cell 3 I transform mydf itno 2 parts X, y = transform(mydf) so X should be fine. Anyway mydf does not work as well. Thanks for helping me solve question 2. But the last one Question 3 is not solved.

Comment: If I try to ues `cv.cross_val_score(pipeline, XoneColumn.values, y, cv=folds, scoring=kappaScore)`.values here the same error persists

Comment: So what is XoneColumn here? looking at your notebook it should work but something is going squiffy here, I'd debug the `transform` and the splitting and single column, for instance does `X['numeric1']` itself work

Comment: Indeed that works

Comment: you may have some temporary variables or shadowing going on, I'd look at what `type(XoneColumn)` prints and also try re-running your code or a restarted kernel just to eliminate any temporary status issues

Comment: This indeed shows me a pandas dataframe. Restarting the notebook does not work.

Comment: I updated the notebook to reflect your suggestions.

Comment: has anyone found a solution for this w/o creating a custom class? I just have some boolean variables and need to include them in my sklearn pipeline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FunctionTransformer` is used to "lift" a function to a transformation which I think can help with some data cleaning steps. Imagine you have a mostly numeric array and you want to transform it with a Transformer that that will error out if it gets a `nan` (like `Normalize`). You might end up with something like

```
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
...
cross_val_score(pipeline, ...)
```

but maybe you that `fillna` is only required in one transformation so instead of having the `fillna` like above, you have

```
normalize = make_pipeline(
    FunctionTransformer(np.nan_to_num, validate=False),
    Normalize()
)
```

which ends up normalizing it as you want. Then you can use that snippet in  more places without littering your code with `.fillna(0)`

In your example, you're passing in `['numeric1']` which is a `list` and not an extractor like the similarly typed `df[['numeric1']]`. What you may want instead is more like

```
FunctionTransformer(operator.itemgetter(columns))
```

but that still wont work because the object that is ultimately passed into the FunctionTransformer will be an `np.array` and not a `DataFrame`.

In order to do operations on particular columns of a `DataFrame`, you may want to use a library like [sklearn-pandas](https://github.com/paulgb/sklearn-pandas) which allows you to define particular transformers by column.